# How to transform a PointStamped from a frame to another?

Tags: ros, frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I get a PoseStamped in a specific frame and I want to transform it to the coordinates of the point in my base_link frame. I tried to use the tf::Transformer::transformPoint. Is it correct? I still have errors when trying to use it because of the types of the inputs. So I used tf::pointStampedMsgToTF but it still not compile.

```
tf::Stamped<tf::Point> tf_point_stamped_in, tf_point_stamped_out;
tf::pointStampedMsgToTF(goal_stamped,*tf_point_stamped_in);
    
if (!tf::Transformer::transformPoint ("base_link", tf_point_stamped_in, tf_point_stamped_out))
{
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM ("Error converting stamped point from frame "<<goal_stamped->header.frame_id<<"to base_link");
    return;
}
tf::pointStampedTFToMsg(tf_point_stamped_out, goal_stamped_);
```

What is wrong? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215485/how-to-transform-a-pointstamped-from-a-frame-to-another?/) by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-08-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-08-09**:
What error messages do you get? What are the expected parameters of your functions?

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2015-08-10**:
Hi, thanks for your answer! I finally fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I finally found an example of code and it works:

```
tf::TransformListener listener(ros::Duration(10));
listener.transformPoint("base_link", *goal_stamped, goal_stamped_);
```

where goal_stamped is a const geometry_msgs::PointStamped::constPtr (subscribed from a topic) and goal_stamped_ is the geometry_msg::PointStamped that I want to use in my code, with frame_id="base_link" (it is the output of the transformPoint function.

Sorry, I hope it will help others!

---

Originally posted by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) with karma: 170 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2